# c# autoproperty set method and OnPropertyChanged method is not executing

Tags: c#, .net

I have below class -

```
public class Myclass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  public Action FetchFoo()
  {
     var ctx = SynchronizationContext.Current;
     return() => Task.Factory.StartNew(()=>
     {
       _isLoading = true;
       businesslogic(ctx);
       _isLoading = false;
     });
  }

  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

  public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
  {
    PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
    if(handler != null)
    {
       handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
  }


  private bool _isLoading = false;
  public bool IsLoading
  {
    get{ return _isLoading;}
    set
    {
      _isLoading = value;
      OnPropertyChanged("IsLoading");
      commandManager.RefreshCommand.CanExecute();
    }
  }

}
```

The issue here is set method is never getting called. (Though it is setting the valus of IsLoading Properly). Even if I put a break point here, it doesn't come to set method. OnPropertyChanged() method I want to write few business logic which I am not able to. Can  anyone put some insight what wrong I am doing here. Thanks!

Comment: You're not attempting to use the property. You're directly manipulating the field instead.

Comment: Instead of `_isLoading = true;` use the property: `IsLoading = true;`

Comment: Then why do we declare _isLoading even ? Sorry might be a silly question. Just trying to understand here.

Comment: To use it as backing field in the property. The property just wraps around the field.

Comment: @croxy So you are saying instead of below - 
 _isLoading = true;
   //businesslogic
  _isLoading = false;

I should use - 
IsLoading = true;
       //businesslogic
       IsLoading = false;
Am I right ?

Comment: Correct, only use the field (`_isLoading`) inside the Property getter and setters.

Comment: @croxy Thanks. Now it's working but I wonder why my businesslogic(ctx) method is not executing at all?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238911/discussion-between-chikun-and-croxy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method that has the setter is IsLoading, but you're never calling that. You should use

```
IsLoading = true;
```

instead of

```
_isLoading = true;
```

Comment: Thanks. Now it's working but I wonder why my businesslogic(ctx) method is not executing at all?

Comment: I'm guessing your OnPropertyChanged method is throwing some sort of an exception, so it's not going to the next line.